# security.stackexchange.com: It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error

Tags: bug, search

When I go to: https://security.stackexchange.com/ I see:

[image]

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser** Chrome, incognito (78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: Possibly related: [No questions found. Site is down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392212/5989200)

Comment: No repro with Firefox/Windows 10.

Comment: It seems that other people experienced similar problems (at least for some short period of time), judging from the response I got [in Tavern on Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8123212#8123212).

Comment: From experience - just cause it works for some people might not mean its totally fine. Occationally one of a few servers might be on the fritz

Comment: Try while logged in.